# Как разделить одну таблицу на две одинаковые в запросе

Tags: sql, oracle

Создал я запрос, который на удивление правильно работал несмотря на то, что у меня ошибочно вышло не правильное соединение, суть заключается в том что мне нужно ввести индекс отделения отправления и отделения получения и я должен получить в ответе эти индексы и описание, например адресс, тип, название отделения.
Структура такая, есть таблица Postoffice с колонами ID, POSTINDEX, ADDRESS, NAME.
я сделал что-то типа такого

```
SELECT sender.postindex AS senderPostindex, 
       sender.ADDRESS as senderAdress, 
       sender.NAME as senderName,    
       recipient.postindex AS recipientPostindex, 
       recipient.ADDRESS as recipientAdress, 
       recipient.NAME as recipient Name
from POSTOFFICE p
INNER JOIN POSTOFFICE sender on sender.id = p.id
INNER JOIN POSTOFFICE recipient on recipient.id = p.id
WHERE :s = sender.postindex 
  and :r = recipient.postindex
```

в :s и :r я вбиваю индексы, к примеру 01001 и 65004
и мне должно выдать:

```
01001, Пушкинская 50, Отделение Одесса 01, 65004, Ришельевская 1, Отделение Харьков 04
```

к сожалению такой запрос выдает мне пустое поле, на сколько я понимаю что-то подобное можно делать через UNION, но вот вопрос можно ли сделать так что бы такой ответ у меня выдавался в одной строке вот таким вот обычным sql запросом?подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Показывайте DDL таблиц, пример исходных данных, значения параметров и требуемый результат для этих данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, просто

```
SELECT sender.postindex AS senderPostindex, 
       sender.ADDRESS as senderAdress, 
       sender.NAME as senderName,    
       recipient.postindex AS recipientPostindex, 
       recipient.ADDRESS as recipientAdress, 
       recipient.NAME as recipient Name
FROM       POSTOFFICE sender 
CROSS JOIN POSTOFFICE recipient 
WHERE :s = sender.postindex 
  and :r = recipient.postindex
```

Answer (score 2):

Это называется `non-equi-self-join`. Чтобы быстрее работало сделал с корреляционным подзапросом:

```
with t (id, pidx, addr, name) as (
    select 1, '01001', 'Пушкинская 50',  'Отделение Одесса 01'  from dual union all
    select 2, '65004', 'Ришельевская 1', 'Отделение Харьков 04' from dual)
select * 
from t s 
cross apply (
    select * 
    from t r where r.id != s.id) r
where s.pidx = '01001' and r.pidx='65004' 
/

 ID PIDX  ADDR             NAME                  ID PIDX  ADDR             NAME                
--- ----- ---------------- -------------------- --- ----- ---------------- --------------------
  1 01001 Пушкинская 50    Отделение Одесса 01    2 65004 Ришельевская 1   Отделение Харьков 04
```

---

На старых версиях:

```
select * 
from t s join t r on s.id != r.id
where s.pidx = '01001' and r.pidx='65004'
```

Answer (score 0):

Таблицы sender и recipient никак не связаны меж собой
просто с каждой нужно взять по одной строке

```
SELECT
    s.postindex AS senderPostindex,
    s.ADDRESS as senderAdress,
    s.NAME as senderName,
    r.postindex AS recipientPostindex,
    r.ADDRESS as recipientAdress,
    r.NAME as recipient Name
from
    POSTOFFICE s
    cross join POSTOFFICE r
WHERE
    :s = s.postindex 
    and :r = r.postindex
```